# Multiple inner joins in MySql not working

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables :

**useractivitylog**

```
id   userid   activity_type  activity_id   date
```

which will store all user activities.

**requestfriend**

```
opid  userid  friendid  requesttime  message  source  requesttype  friendemail  status
```

which will store friends details. *userid* and *friendid* can be the user's id. If user A has send friend's request to user B, then *userid* will contain the id of A and *friendid* will be the id of B. So anyway B is the friend of A and A is the friend of B.

**auth_user_profiles**

```
id  user_id  first_name  last_name  profileimage
```

which stores user profile information.

What I need is to select all my friends activities from *useractivitylog* table. I tried with the following query. But it didnt worked.

```
    echo "select ua.*,rf.opid,aup.user_id,aup.first_name,aup.last_name,
        aup.profileimage from useractivitylog as ua INNER JOIN requestfriend as rf 
   INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles as aup on
   aup.user_id= IF (rf.userid='$userid',rf.friendid,rf.userid) 
   WHERE (rf.userid=$userid or rf.friendid=$userid)
   and rf.status='2' and ua.userid!=$userid";
```

Here, `$userid` is my user id. Actually what I want is to retrieve the profile information and the activities of users who are friends of mine. But know, it is returning all rows in *useractivitylog* table even if the *userid* is not in my friends list.

Can anyone help me to find an appropriate query for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain *But it didnt worked* ? any error or something else

Comment: It is returning all rows even if the user in useractivitylog table is not my friend.

Comment: you have two JOINs but only one condition in ON clause, this seems likely to be the culprit.

Comment: thanks RobP..It worked with echo "select ua.*,rf.opid,aup.user_id,aup.first_name,aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage from useractivitylog as ua INNER JOIN requestfriend as rf  on 
        (ua.userid=rf.userid or ua.userid=rf.friendid)
   INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles as aup on
   aup.user_id= IF (rf.userid='$userid',rf.friendid,rf.userid) 
   WHERE (rf.userid=$userid or rf.friendid=$userid)
   and rf.status='2' and ua.userid!=$userid";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't join properly. The only condition for a useractivitylog being linked to the other tables is that its user ID is not $userid. That is true for most records in the table, so you almost get a cartesian product (cross join).

BTW: You don't join auth_user_profiles properly either, because you compare with the string '$userid' instead of comparing with $userid.

Let's re-write the statement such that we retrieve the friends first and join the other tables with these:

```
select 
  ua.*,
  friend.opid,
  aup.user_id,
  aup.first_name,
  aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage 
from 
(
  select distinct
    case when userid = $userid then friendid else userid end as id,
    opid
  from requestfriend
  where $userid in (userid, friendid) and status = '2'
) as friend
inner join useractivitylog as ua on ua.userid = friend.id
inner join auth_user_profiles as aup on aup.user_id = friend.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as you explained you need to get the activities of users who are friends with you, you first need to join `useractivitylog` table to `requestfriend` where  `friendid` is in `useractivitylog`  i.e  `ON(rf.friendid =ua.userid)` then you need to join `auth_user_profiles` table where `userid` from `useractivitylog` table is equal,i.e `ON(ua.userid=aup.user_id)` and then use you where filter on `rf.userid`  is equal to the provided user id ,i didn't get the point of using `OR rf.friendid = $userid` comparison when you asked for the friends activity then why comparing friend's id to the given user id

```
SELECT 
  ua.*,
  rf.opid,
  aup.user_id AS aup_user_id,
  aup.first_name,
  aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage 
FROM
  useractivitylog AS ua 
  INNER JOIN requestfriend AS rf ON(rf.friendid =ua.userid)
  INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles AS aup ON(ua.userid=aup.user_id)

WHERE 
  rf.userid = $userid      
  AND rf.status = '2'
```

Using a sub select

```
SELECT 
  ua.*,  
  aup.user_id AS aup_user_id,
  aup.first_name,
  aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage 
FROM
  useractivitylog AS ua 
  INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles AS aup ON(ua.userid=aup.user_id)
WHERE 
ua.userid IN (
SELECT friendid  FROM  requestfriend WHERE userid =$userid AND `status` = '2' 
)
```

Comment: this is showing all records in useractivitylog where userid is my id..actually what I need is to show all activities of my friends.. not mine..

Comment: @Jenz i guess the joined query should works as expected for you desired result set i have also provided another solution see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try as below query

```
select * from useractivitylog a,requestfriend b,auth_user_profiles c 
   WHERE a.userid = b.userid and b.userid = c.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a field to JOIN your first table on:

```
SELECT ua.*, rf.opid, aup.user_id, aup.first_name, aup.last_name, aup.profileimage 
  FROM useractivitylog as ua 
       INNER JOIN requestfriend as rf on fieldname = fieldname
       INNER JOIN auth_user_profiles as aup on aup.user_id = IF (rf.userid='$userid',rf.friendid,rf.userid) 
 WHERE (rf.userid=$userid or rf.friendid=$userid)
   AND rf.status='2' 
   AND ua.userid!=$userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go from the other side to your data... 
Start with selecting all your friends and if you have them, get their data:

```
SELECT 
  ua.*,
  rf.opid,
  aup.user_id,
  aup.first_name,
  aup.last_name,
  aup.profileimage
FROM
  requestfriend AS rf
JOIN 
  useractivitylog AS ua ON (ua.userid = rf.friendid)
JOIN 
  auth_user_profiles AS uap ON (uap.userid = rf.friendid)
WHERE rf.userid = $userid AND rf.status = '2'
```

The rest with the vice-versa connection in your requestfriend table should be no problem.

Since the friendrequests should be not as much as the activities, this might lead to better performance in case you have loads of data...